# Change structure of object JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have object

```
const obj1 = {
app: {groups: [{name: 'test},{name: 'test2'}],
ap2: {groups: [{name: 'test1'},{name: 'test3'}],
}
```

How to change to this:

```
const obj1 = {
groups: [{name: 'test, type: 'app'},{name: 'test2', type: 'app'}, {name: 'test1, type: 'app2'},{name: 'test33', type: 'app2'}],
}
```

Comment: typos in the examples? Missing quotes and there is comma in excess

Comment: Have you tried a loop?

Comment: Try `for ...in` loop for objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the typos in the original code, you could do something like that:

```
const obj1 = {
  app: {groups: [{name: 'test'},{name: 'test2'}]},
  app2: {groups: [{name: 'test1'},{name: 'test3'}]},
}

const obj2 = {
  groups: Object.entries(obj1).flatMap(([type, {groups}]) => 
    groups.map( ({name}) => ({name, type}) )
  )
}

console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: Sweet and simple :-) I would however recommend to use `flatMap` instead of `reduce` + `concat`.

Comment: Thanks. :) Could you elaborate a bit more how you would use the `flatMap`? Bacause given the approach I suggested, you don't have nested arrays where you can use `flat` (or `flatMap`) easily (because there are objects "between" the arrays), and that's why I decided to use `reduce` and `concat`, I needed more granularity.

Comment: `flatMap` doesn't need nested arrays, it's used where a plain `map` would *produce* a nested array.

Comment: @Bergi but that's the point, how would you use it in this scenario, to replace `reduce` and `contact` as you suggested? I can't see it without overcomplicate the code instead of simplify, so I would very appreciate if you could show me how to do so in this case.

Comment: See the edit I had made to your answer. Feel free to roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: Ah, I see now: I though you wanted to replace also the `map` inside, that what it got me sideways. Much better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but readable;

```js
const obj1 = {
 app: {
  groups: [
  {name: 'test'},
  {name: 'test2'}
  ]
 },
 ap2: {
  groups: [
  {name: 'test1'},
  {name: 'test3'}
  ],
 }
}

const obj2 = {};
obj2.groups = [];
Object.keys(obj1).forEach( function(element) {
 obj1[element]['groups'].forEach( function(e) {
  var temp = {};
  temp.name = e.name;
  temp.type = element;
  obj2.groups.push(temp)
 });
});
console.log(obj2);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var midObj = {name: '', type: ''};
var obj = {groups: []};
for(var I in obj1) {
  for(var j=0; j<obj1[I]['groups'].length; j++) {
    midObj = {};
    midObj.type = I;
    midObj.name = obj1[I]['groups'][j].name;
    obj['groups'].push(midObj);
  }
}
```

**Assumptions: the source object define only as: const obj1 = { app: {groups: [{name: 'test},{name: 'test2'}], ap2: {groups: [{name: 'test1'},{name: 'test3'}], }**

*the solution works only for the mentioned source object. in order to do the same manipulation but with another source object it require to change the loops and their content*

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: This would throw error on `midObj['groups'].push(midObj);` because `midObj['groups']` is undefined and you reassign `midObj` in every iteration